# how do i parse a value in data table to master page from content page on button click event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a label called Lblcountcart on my master page. I have set the virtual path of the master page on my content page. I have also created a public property of the label on the master page. from my content page i am able to get access to the property of the label but when i parse the data the label on my master page still remains empty thus i dont see the data i parsed. below is my code

```
//on my master page
Public Property cartcountitems As Label

Get
    cartcountitems = Me.Lblcountcart()
    Return Lblcountcart
End Get
Set(value As Label)
    Lblcountcart.Text.ToString()
End Set
End Property

//my content page 
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/mysitemaster2.Master" %>

//code behind of my contentpage

Dim selcartcountda As New SqlDataAdapter(selcartcount)
Dim selcartcountdt As New DataTable()
selcartcountda.Fill(selcartcountdt)
Master.cartcountitems.Text = selcartcountdt.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: ok thanks very much Actually what I realized is that my content page was in an update panel while my mster page was not so the data is actually being passed but just that my muster page was not updating to show up the data

Comment: You can answer your own question and 2 days later accept your own answer. This will help future readers.